# Download 64-bit rpm package on 32-bit machine

Tags: redhat, yum, rpm

I want to download some rpm packages from a rpmforge repo. My base machine is running CentOS 32 bit and I want to download some 64-bit packages.

Is there any way in which we can configure YUM on a 32-bit machine to fetch and cache 64-bit packages ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Download package from here instead: http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/

You can `wget` or just download the package you want.

FYI, 32-bit is here: http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/i386/CentOS/